# C:\System Volume Information\_restore{6E3D25DD-2E98-4D88-BAA4-DA84E0DB2D6D}\RP126

Tags: windows, windows-xp, audio, restore

After running disk space analyser , I found a large folder on C labeled :C:\System Volume Information_restore{6E3D25DD-2E98-4D88-BAA4-DA84E0DB2D6D}\RP126 . and it occupy a big space on the partition . can I safely remove it ? , is it necessary ? and how to prevent the system from forming such files in future ?

Answer (score 0):

It is part of System Restore. It is necessary to restore your computer to previous points like before and after installing a new program or driver. If you still want to remove it, **do not** remove it manually. Instead follow the steps documented in these Microsoft articles:

### Windows XP:

How to turn off and turn on System Restore in Windows XP (http://support.microsoft.com/kb/310405)

### Windows Vista:

What is System Restore? (http://windows.microsoft.com/en-gb/windows/what-is-system-restore#1TC=windows-vista)

Turning System Restore on or off in Windows Vista (http://windows.microsoft.com/en-gb/windows/turn-system-restore-on-off#1TC=windows-vista)

### Windows 7 or 8:

What is System Restore? (http://windows.microsoft.com/en-gb/windows/what-is-system-restore#1TC=windows-7)

Turning System Restore on or off in Windows 7 (http://windows.microsoft.com/en-gb/windows/turn-system-restore-on-off#1TC=windows-7)

---

If you would like to read more details about System Restore itself, take a look at this FAQ page:

System Restore: frequently asked questions (http://windows.microsoft.com/en-gb/windows/system-restore-faq#1TC=windows-7)